# How to search OR with Laravel QueryBuilder

Tags: php, laravel

I need to search every Message that contains **one** of the words delivered in $msg (1 to X words possible).

My Code search with AND, so i get only Messages that contains all words in $msg. I like to do the same thing with OR.

```
$words = explode(' ', $msg);
$search = [];
foreach($words as $word){
    $search[] = ['rawtext', 'LIKE', '%'.$word.'%'];
}
$messages_search = Message::where($search)->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$messages_search = Message::where(function ($query) use ($words) {
  foreach ($words as $word) {
    $query->orWhere('rawtext', 'like', '%' . $word . '%');
  }
})->get();
```

try this code ..